# Does the API key replace a username and a password in Nuget?

Tags: nuget

After running `nuget setapikey`, I still get a prompt for credentials in Visual Studio 2015 during package restore. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-setapikey) says the API key "Applies to: package consumption". Does that mean it is used for authentication, similar to a username and a password?

Things I've tried:

- Checked that the API key has been added to `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`.
- Restarted Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6415 the api key saved via `nuget setapikey` is used for publishing packages, but not for consuming them.

Comment: It looks like you can use an API key for consuming packages, not just for publishing; you just can't use it with `setapikey`. Sources: https://mallibone.com/post/private-nuget-feed-azure-devops, https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9425#issuecomment-1109502136